# Change Style of mxCell

Tags: jgraphx

I have to re-engineer a Java program which uses the old version 5 of [JGraph](https://www.jgraph.com/). I have to replace this package with the new version 6.
It was possible in version 5 to create a cell with an HTML-Object, so I could change the style of a cell into a style which looks like a database table.
Is it possible to change the style of a [`mxCell`](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxCell-js.html) like this with user object oder other methods in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom vertices that may use any [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) components when rendering. Create a custom vertex that uses a Swing component that supports HTML (and a good number of them do). Displaying the HTML label string directly to the component will cause it to render the HTML correctly.